# Audio sink missing from pulseaudio

Tags: audio, linux-mint, pulse-audio

Last night I was having the usual issue: Audio stops working after resuming from hibernate. The usual fix is to reboot the system, but I thought I'd tinker a little bit back and forth and see if I managed to fix it without a reboot. Unfortunately I can't for the life of me remember exactly what it was a did, tho. This had two effects:

1. It started working again without having to reboot
2. Upon next boot (today), audio does not work at all. Unsuprisingly, rebooting again does not help.

I only remember that I ran `alsa force-reload` as part of the troubleshooting.

After checking, it seems that my current problem is that the audio sink I used to have listed under `pavucontrol` is not there anymore. Running `pacmd list-sinks` only shows the displayport output, which I next to never use:

```
>>> 1 sink(s) available.
  * index: 0
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.hdmi-stereo>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: IDLE
    suspend cause: 
    priority: 9950
[SNIP]
    card: 0 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0>
    module: 4
    properties:
[SNIP]
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "1c20"
        device.product.name = "6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "hdmi:0"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "32768"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "hdmi-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Digital Stereo (HDMI)"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio Digital Stereo (HDMI)"
[SNIP]
```

The main sink that I used to have is simply not there anymore. I can't remember the name of it, but it was something generic along the lines of `builtin speakers/headphones`.

output of `lspci | grep -i audio`

```
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
```

Any assistance on how to find this missing audio sink would be much appreciated. If more info is needed, comment, and I'll append.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured that whatever I did last night must've messed up something regarding pulseaudio, so I decided to do a complete wipe and restart of both pulseaudio and alsa:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio
sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio
```

While I do not know the exact issue, the above did the trick for me.